# Qt- How to position UI elements like this?

Tags: qt, user-interface

I am creating a UI in Qt that has a QDockWidget containing a QPushButton and QLineEdit. Please refer to the attached mock-up. I have created the widget components and successfully got them up and running. However they are not positioned the way I want them to. Both the elements should float to the left making the extra space to the right stretch when the window is resized.

[image: Mock up]

The code-

```
this->searchField = new QLineEdit;         //"this" is a QDockWidget subclassed Object
searchField->setFixedWidth(200);
mainMenu = new Menu();                    
QHBoxLayout *layout= new QHBoxLayout;
QSpacerItem *filler = new QSpacerItem(1000, 10);
layout->addWidget(mainMenu->getMenuBar());
layout->addWidget(this->searchField);
layout->addSpacerItem(filler);
```

Any suggestion or help would be awesome!
Thanks for your time :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/layout.html

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qboxlayout.html#addStretch

```
void QBoxLayout::addStretch ( int stretch = 0 )
```

> Adds a stretchable space (a QSpacerItem) with zero minimum size and stretch factor stretch to the end of this box layout.

So this is what your new code would look like:

```
this->searchField = new QLineEdit;
searchField->setFixedWidth(200);
mainMenu = new Menu();                    
QHBoxLayout *layout= new QHBoxLayout;
layout->addWidget(mainMenu->getMenuBar());
layout->addWidget(this->searchField);
layout->addStretch(); // Added this
```

Hope that helps.